# React-router-dom not rendering component and Getting error GET http://localhost:8080/editor 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-router, http-status-code-404

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03Ox2.png)

```
<Fragment>
       <Routes>
         <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />}></Route>
         <Route exact path="/editor" element={<EditorPad />} />
          <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/" />} />
        </Routes>
      </Fragment>
```

I tried to use this as well

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <Router>
    <App />
  </Router>
);
```

But it's not working. I am using react 18

```
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-router": "^6.4.4",
"react-router-dom": "^6.4.4",
```

Please help me out
Thanks

Comment: What do you get when you hover `Router`?

Comment: This is an issue with how the server is configured to serve your React app, as servers are what return status 404 errors. The server needs to return the root index.html file for ***all*** page requests. See the CRA [deployment](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/) docs to get a general idea what different server environments require to be configured correctly. Feel free to edit your post to include the relevant deployment details like where you are deploying the app and what configurations you are using.

Comment: @DrewReese I think that's answer-worthy rather than a comment :)

Comment: @DrewReese Thank you for answering. I am not yet deploying my project,  running it on my local machine(local host)

Comment: How are you running/serving the app locally then? Are you running some custom webpack and/or scripts?

Comment: yeah, actually I tried to create-react-app but unfortunately, I was getting some error so I tried to create react app manually and added some webpack config const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const path = require("path");
module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  mode: "development",
  output: {
    filename: "bundle.[hash].js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./src/index.html",
    }),
  ],
 ..... module ....{ ...}  and starting my app by npm start

Comment: Try adding `</Route>` after addition of `/editor` and `/*` routes.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried :

```js
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
);
```